# Mixing Cpp and Fortran in Xcode: Clang -lgfortran?

Tags: xcode, gcc, clang

I have a Cpp project where I have to include some Fortran subroutines. What I am doing until now is:

1. compile Fortran files without linking: `gfortran -c testF.f`
2. compile Cpp files without linking: `gcc -c testC.cpp`
3. link the binaries: `gcc -o test testC.o testF.o -lgfortran`

I am used to code my project in XCode which uses the **Apple LLVM 8.8** compiler with **Clang**. To keep the workflow I wanted to know:

> Is there is a similar linking (**-lgfortran**) for Clang?

And if not what would be the approach to mix Cpp and Fortran within XCode?